# Prime factor of $14 \uparrow \uparrow 3 + 15\uparrow \uparrow 3$ wanted

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, prime-factorization, tetration

Checking the prime factors of the numbers

$$z(a,b) \ := a \uparrow \uparrow 3 \ +\  b \uparrow \uparrow 3 \ ,$$

a,b positive integers with a < b

the number

$$z(14,15) = 14 \uparrow \uparrow 3 \ +\ 15 \uparrow \uparrow 3 = 14^{14^{14}}+15^{15^{15}}$$

turned out to be a candidate surviving trial division up to $10^{10}$.

Of course, $z(14,15)$ still has a very low chance to be prime, so I 
search a prime factor. Any ideas how the search can be accelerated ?
Can ECM or similar methods be used to find factors of numbers of this
magnitude (about $10^{10^{18}}$) ?

Comment: If $$x\uparrow \uparrow y\implies x^y, $$ we can start with $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$

Comment: Note the tag "tetration". $a \uparrow \uparrow 3$ means $a \uparrow a \uparrow a$

Comment: And what does $x\uparrow y$ mean? Is it power $x^y$? or what?

Comment: Any method which needs to be able to operate with the explicit representation of the actual number (as opposed to just its compact representation) is doomed to fail due to the memory requirements -- $10^{18}$ bits is a bit too much :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, ECM actually needs the extended GCD to compute inverses modulo $n$ -- and multiplicative inverses of even small elements tend to be quite big (i.e. roughly the same bit-size as $n$) and not having any "compact" representation.

Comment: Pollard $p-1$ is troublesome too, since it computes modular exponentiation with quite high exponent modulo $n$; again, the result will be on the same order of magnitude as $n$ itself. \

Comment: So does the number $14 \uparrow \uparrow 3 + 15\uparrow \uparrow 3$ just mean $ \left( \left( 14^3 \right)^3 \right)^3 + \left( \left( 15^3 \right)^3 \right)^3 $? Am I misunderstanding? I'm confused.

Comment: @Ahaan: $f(14,15)=14^{14^{14}}+15^{15^{15}}$

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Oh, that makes so much more sense and makes it harder, thanks! :)

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to factorize $14 \uparrow  \uparrow 3 -1 $ up to not too small primefactors and  similarly $15 \uparrow  \uparrow 3 +1 $ and then look at gcd. But I didn't check this myself...

Comment: (14^^4+15^^4) is divisible by 1823, assuming I programmed the combination of "right to left binary method" of binary exponentiation; see Wikipedia Modular exponentiation, and Fermat's little theorem ... :)  Using the same method, I haven't found any factors for (14^^3+15^^3), up to 2E9

Comment: @Sheldon If you find a factor, please tell it me ...

Comment: @SheldonL This could interest you as well : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636761/how-does-one-prove-that-2-uparrow-uparrow161-is-composite