# How does one prove that $(2\uparrow\uparrow16)+1$ is composite?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization, big-numbers

**Just to be clear, close observation will show that this is not the Fermat numbers.**

I was reading [some things (link)](https://books.google.com/books/about/An_Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Numbers.html?id=P6uTBqOa3T4C&source=kp_read&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false) when I came across the footnote on page 21, which states the following:

$$F_1=2+1\to prime$$

$$F_2=2^2+1\to prime$$

$$F_3=2^{2^2}+1\to prime$$

$$F_4=2^{2^{2^{2}}}+1\to ?$$

And so on.  Amazingly, it has been found that $F_1$ through $F_{15}$ to be prime, but, at $F_{16}$, the answer is no longer prime (proven?).

In [knuth arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation#Computing_2.E2.86.91mn):

$$F_{16}=(2\uparrow\uparrow16)+1\to composite$$

But how do you prove this?  $F_{16}$ is so large, that I cannot proceed to manually attempt at factoring it, and, most likely, many of its factors will have hundreds (or more) digits!

Interestingly, people have pointed out that there are only $5$ known Fermat numbers are prime, and so, I have come to a different conclusion.

Numbers such as $F_{15}$ or $F_{14}$ are unknown as to whether they are prime or composite.  However, it has been *proven*, somehow, that $F_{16}$ is composite.

**But how?**

Comment: I removed my last comment, I thought this was referring to the Fermat numbers. Apparently, this is a different sequence.

Comment: @M10687 Yes.  It increases the amount of $2's$ in this sequence.

Comment: I can see that this is not the sequence of Fermat numbers, but isn't it a subsequence of the Fermat numbers? We have $$F_1=2^{2^0}+1\\F_2=2^{2^1}+1\\F_3=2^{2^2}+1\\F_4=2^{2^4}+1\\F_5=2^{2^{16}}+1$$and so on.

Comment: @Arthur It is, but just because some of the Fermat numbers isn't prime doesn't mean all Fermat numbers larger than $f_n$ are composite.

Comment: @SimpleArt I know, but I thought that only five Fermat primes were known to mankind, and here you are listing fifteen Fermat numbers (not the fifteen first terms, but still), claiming they are all prime. I might be missing something, but to me it looks very suspect.

Comment: @Arthur What are you trying to hint at?

Comment: @Arthur Well, I am sorry.  Perhaps the source of my link is incorrect.  And to state that only 5 Fermat primes are known?  Where'd you get that?

Comment: @Arthur You guys are talking about different sequences. Arthur is talking about the actual Fermat primes, while Simple Art is talking about a subsequence of the Fermat primes that uses [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).

Comment: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A019434) says it is conjectured that there are only five, so does [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number). And @NobleMushtak I know that this is a subsequence of the Fermat numbers $2^{2^n}+1$, but as is said in the links in this very comment, only five primes are known on that form at all, let alone for $n$ of the form $2\uparrow \uparrow m$.

Comment: Well, he kind of makes a good point.  However, that hints that my source is false (which it can, of course, be), but how do I go about proving it prime or not?

Comment: Oh...I see what you're saying now. Simple Art's sequence says that there must be $15$ Fermat primes, which is clearly up for debate. Also, according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPrime.html), Arthur is right: We only know five Fermat primes. The rest of the Fermat numbers we know are composite.

Comment: On page 18 of [your source](https://books.google.com/books/about/An_Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Numbers.html?id=P6uTBqOa3T4C&source=kp_read&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q=fermat&f=false), the book clearly agrees with @Arthur.

Comment: Well, yes, it is up to debate, but how do I prove if it is prime or not?

Comment: @NobleMushtak Whats up with the footnote on page 21 then?

Comment: The footnote in the link only covers fairly "small numbers" . That is, it correctly points out that $3,5,17,65537$ are prime and it asserts without proof that $2^{2^{16}}+1$ is composite.  The latter has had a known factor ($825753601$) for some time.

Comment: You misunderstood the footnote. That sequence is $F_1$, $F_2$, $F_4$, $F_8$, $F_{16}$, and so on. The first four numbers of that sequence (${F_1, F_2, F_4, F_8}$) are known to be prime while $F_{16}$ is composite.

Comment: Noble Mushtak : "The rest of the Fermat numbers we know are composite"?.  No. We know the other Fermat numbers up to $F_{32}$, and some others, are composite.  As far as we know, all sufficiently large Fermat numbers could be primes.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Sorry, I meant "the rest of the Fermat numbers that we know the primality of are composite."

Comment: @NobleMushtak I've updated the question accordingly to what I have deduced from the comments/answers

Comment: @lulu No, actually, $F_{16}$ is equivalent to:$$2^{2^{2^{\dots}}}+1$$ where there are $15$ 2's.

Comment: @SimpleArt Also, after reading the footnote again, the footnote actually isn't talking about tetration because otherwise, the sequence would be $F_1$, $F_2$, $F_4$, $F_{16}$, and $F_{65536}$. The sequence in the footnote forgot its parentheses to show that it was talking about $2^{2^n}+1$ and not tetration.

Comment: @SimpleArt You are misreading the footnote.

Comment: In my defense, it appears very clear that this is most likely a tetration thing.

Comment: "Numbers such as $F_{15}$ or $F_{14}$ are unknown as to whether they are prime or composite:" No, $F_{15}$ and $F_{14}$ are known to be composite. $F_n$ for $n=3$, $5 \leq n \leq 32$, and other larger values of $n$ are known to be composite.

Comment: @NobleMushtak In my notation, I meant to say that this sequence is $F_n$, whereas the Fermat numbers are $f_n$.  Sorry.

Comment: @SimpleArt The footnote looks like it is tetration, but after reading closer, it's a typo. Otherwise, $F_{16}$ would be the fourth element, not the the fifth as they say it is.

Comment: @SimpleArt: what is your source for the claim in the sentence in your question beginning "Amazingly"? The footnote in Hardy & Wright doesn't justify it (and it would be amazing if it did).

Comment: Ok.  I guess I'll turn this down.  The question is still open to anyone who wants to compute the primality of $2\uparrow\uparrow15+1$.

Comment: That's not the notation your book is using, though. Your book is using the same notation @Arthur and everyone else.

Comment: @NobleMushtak But if they were the Fermat numbers, then it would've been quickly shown that $F_0=2^{2^{0}}+1$ and that $F_1=2^{2^{1}}+1$ or something along those lines.  My notation is equivalent to it for the terms shown, and I only meant to condense it for $F_{16}$

Comment: We can continue this on the morrow.

Comment: @SimpleArt OK, but in the meantime, just realize that $2 \uparrow \uparrow 15+1$ is a huge number and I do not think anyone could ever find out its primality with current technology.

Comment: The conjecture that the sequence $F_n$ contains infinitely many primes (or is all primes) goes back to Eisenstein, a contemporary of Gauss.

Comment: Hardy and Wright use the standard notation $F_k = 2^{2^k} + 1$ in the footnote. Yet the sequence the conjecture is about is $S_m = 2^{2\uparrow\uparrow m} + 1$, with $S_0 = 2^{2\uparrow\uparrow 0} + 1 = 2^1 + 1 = 2^{2^0} +1 = F_0$, $S_1 = 2^{2\uparrow\uparrow 1} + 1 = 2^{2^1} + 1 = F_1$, $S_2 = 2^{2\uparrow\uparrow 2} + 1 = 2^{2^{2\uparrow\uparrow 1}} + 1 = 2^{2^2} + 1 = F_2$, $S_3 = 2^{2\uparrow\uparrow 3} + 1 = 2^{2^{2\uparrow\uparrow 2}} + 1 = 2^{2^4} + 1 = F_4$, and $S_4 = 2^{2\uparrow\uparrow 4} + 1 = 2^{2^{2\uparrow\uparrow 3}} + 1 = 2^{2^{16}} + 1 = F_{16}$.

Comment: $S_4 = F_{16}$ is the fifth term of the sequence, a large number, but still manageable for today's computers. The sixth, $S_5 = F_{2^{16}}$ is really really large already, with $2^{65536}+1$ bits, far beyond what computers nowadays can deal with (an exabyte is $2^{60}$ bytes, $2^{63}$ bits, an is still far more than the current storage capacities).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, that most certainly explains.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @SimpleArt I edited the question because the pattern seems to be $F_n=(2\uparrow\uparrow n)+1$. But in the comments, $F_{16}$ is said to be $(2\uparrow\uparrow 15)+1$. This would not fit in the pattern.

Comment: Interesting, that Fermat conjectured that all numbers of the form $2^{2^n}+1$ are prime. Euler disproved it by finding $641|2^{32}+1$ and today the opposite of Fermat's conjecture (No more Fermat primes) is conjectured. But, it has to be pointed out, that it is still possible that infinite many Fermat primes exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $N = 2^k + 1$ is composite when $k$ has an odd factor $p$, since then $2^p + 1$ will divide $N$.

The converse is false. The first five possibilities, corresponding to $k = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16$ are prime. Euler showed the next one isn't. No more primes of this form have been found. Some of the next ones have been proved to be composite (but not necessarily factored).

The wikipedia page is a reliable reference. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Primality_of_Fermat_numbers

Comment: Is wikipedia really reliable?  Also, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @SimpleArt Wikipedia is quite reliable for established mathematics. (Not for politics.)

Comment: Well, good to know what sources I can trust.

Answer (score 1):

The status of the fermat numbers is shown very well here : http://www.prothsearch.net/fermat.html

The numbers you are interested are very special Fermat numbers.

A prime factor of $2^{2^n}+1$ must have the form $k\cdot 2^{n+2}+1$.

It is open whether there are finite or infinite many Fermat primes, the smallest $n$, for which the character of $2^{2^n}+1$ is unknown, is $33$.

To prove that the number $(2\uparrow\uparrow 16)+1$ is composite, you have to find a prime factor (Primilaty check is out of reach with the known prime checking methods), but this factor must have the form $k\cdot 2^{(2\uparrow\uparrow 14)+2}+1$ , so it must be greater than $2\uparrow\uparrow 15$.

Such a factor cannot be verified by the usual modulo division, so we need special number-theoretical tricks. If we do not have such tricks, it is hopeless to find a factor.