# With googolplex=G, smallest prime factor of either (G/2-783, G/2+783)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $G$=googolplex.

I tested a technique for [splitting a googolplex into rough numbers](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/994246).

$(\frac{G}{2} -3, \frac{G}{2} +3)$ have smallest prime divisor 149 between them.

$(\frac{G}{2} -783, \frac{G}{2} +783)$ have no known prime factors.  Checked for all primes under 5852719141 at this moment.

I wasn't expecting to find a split this rough with a relatively small number like 783.

Can anyone find a prime factor for either of $(\frac{G}{2} -783, \frac{G}{2} +783)$?

Comment: Nicely detected! I think the only way to find a prime factor (perhaps!) is to continue the brute-force-search.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624030/prime-factor-of-14-uparrow-uparrow-3-15-uparrow-uparrow-3-wanted?rq=1